# How to call plt.subplots() without opening GUI?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to run a deep learning training that uses matplotlib internally for creating graphs and then use the created figure and dump it to disk as image.

The dumping part is done for me using `tensorboardX` and that part works.

The problem:

`plt.subplots(4, 1)` opens a window, which slows down my program, especially when not all figures get closed upon request.

I want the same functionality without GUI:

- Create the subplots.
- Plot into them.
- Have a figure object with the plots drawn (and not shown on screen) and do whatever I want with it.

---

Sample code (in pytorch-lightning) for context only, I don't expect anyone to have to reproduce this, as the question is clear.

```
tb = self.logger.experiment
fig, axs = plt.subplots(n_plots, 1)
    for sample_idx in range(n_plots):
        for feature_idx, (orig_feature, recon_feature) in enumerate(zip(orig_batch_view[sample_idx + first_sample_idx, :, :], recon_batch_view[sample_idx + first_sample_idx, :, :])):
            i = feature_idx
            if i > 0: continue  # or scale issues don't allow informative plotting                     

                axs[sample_idx].plot(orig_feature.detach().cpu().numpy(), label=f'orig{i}, sample{sample_idx}')
                axs[sample_idx].plot(recon_feature.detach().cpu().numpy(), label=f'recon{i}, sample{sample_idx}')
          
                axs[sample_idx].legend(loc='upper left')
    tb.add_figure(f"{mode}recon_vs_orig", fig, global_step=self.current_epoch, close=True)
```

---

Can it be done?

Comment: @Mr.T OK, how to do that? will it leave me with a figure object to work with?

Comment: To switch a backend add `plt.switch_backend('agg')` after you make an import `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Comment: @AlexeyLukyanov how to switch back?

Comment: Forget my suggestion, Gulzar. I just tried it; that does not work as I thought it might. However, looking at your code, it is not clear why a window should open. plt.subplots() by itself does not initiate the renderer to create an output window. Have you turned on interactive mode and somewhere else, the plt.show() command takes effect? Or do you work in an environment like Jupyter that does this for you? If so, this should be mentioned in the question and tagged accordingly.

Comment: Just because I started it: You can check and store the current backend with `my_backend = matplotlib.get_backend()`. How to switch has already been explained.

Comment: @Mr.T I did not turn it on to my awareness. I am using pytorch-lightning which does things behind the scenes but I highly doubt they do it.

Comment: I think matplotlib opens the figure automatically even if plt.show() hasn't been called. Thanks for the question and the answer, helped me a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by @Mr.T, I investigated some more and got a similar solution with different syntax.

```
matplotlib.use('Agg')  # turn off gui
fig, axs = plt.subplots(n_plots, 1)
...
matplotlib.use('QT4Agg')  # turn on gui
```

Comment: When I use the `Agg` backend, no window opens when I call `plt.subplots` (which it shouldn't), but Matplotlib also completely fails to save the rendered image to a PNG file. I create a plot with `pcolormesh`, and besides add a colorbar, but in the saved image I get no plotted data and no colorbar, and I get tickmarks with labels along the x and y axes, which shouldn't be there.